# How do I get code that exists on my box into source control using RTC jazz

Tags: rtc, jazz

Basically I somehow got out of sync somewhere. We were using VS 2010 with RTC 3.0. We cannot upgrade to RTC 4.0 until it gets approved and goes through the bureaucratic red tape. I edited my project in VS2012 because I thought I would use the RTC client to deliver my changes to the stream; however, that did not work. I went back to VS2010 where we have Built in RTC abilities. That however is also out of sync. When I make changes to my product the pending changes area no longer shows that I have outgoing changes.

How do I take the code thats on my box currently and get it back into a stream in RTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you reload your project if it is displayed as out of sync.

See "[How to handle project out of sync](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/67602/how-to-handle-project-out-of-sync)".

> the right answer is to re-load, with the "**reload projects out of sync**" action. In my experience, this will never overwrite any of your local changes, and it definitely will not change the date stamp on any file that is currently loaded and in-sync with what is in the repository.

(Still, save your local work just in case)